# How can I use the field_ui_table element in a custom module?

Tags: forms

How can I use the field_ui_table element in a custom module? Is it even possible to use it?

The following code doesn't show anything.

```
$form['menu_builder']['list1'] = array(
  '#type' => 'field_ui_table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#empty' => t('No content available.'),
  '#attributes'=>array('id'=>'menu-builder-table'),
);
```

Comment: Its an element defined by field_ui module. It used in the Manage display of field UI.

Comment: Check this http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field_ui!field_ui.module/7

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [`theme_field_ui_table()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field_ui%21field_ui.admin.inc/function/theme_field_ui_table/7.x), the function that renders the *field_ui_table* element, and [`field_ui_display_overview_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field_ui%21field_ui.admin.inc/function/field_ui_display_overview_form/7.x), a form builder that uses that form element, I can say that:

- Neither *#options* nor *#rows* is used from the rendering function
- Leaving out those two element attributes, the code you shown contains just the declaration of the table; it still needs to define the elements to render in the table, which the render function expects to be a list of fields.

The code adding the fields to be listed as rows of the table is quite complex.

```
  foreach ($instances as $name => $instance) {
    $field = field_info_field($instance['field_name']);
    $display = $instance['display'][$view_mode];
    $table[$name] = array(
      '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array(
          'draggable',
          'tabledrag-leaf',
        ),
      ),
      '#row_type' => 'field',
      '#region_callback' => 'field_ui_display_overview_row_region',
      '#js_settings' => array(
        'rowHandler' => 'field',
        'defaultFormatter' => $field_types[$field['type']]['default_formatter'],
      ),
      'human_name' => array(
        '#markup' => check_plain($instance['label']),
      ),
      'weight' => array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Weight for @title', array(
          '@title' => $instance['label'],
        )),
        '#title_display' => 'invisible',
        '#default_value' => $display['weight'],
        '#size' => 3,
        '#attributes' => array(
          'class' => array(
            'field-weight',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'parent_wrapper' => array(
        'parent' => array(
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#title' => t('Label display for @title', array(
            '@title' => $instance['label'],
          )),
          '#title_display' => 'invisible',
          '#options' => $table['#parent_options'],
          '#empty_value' => '',
          '#attributes' => array(
            'class' => array(
              'field-parent',
            ),
          ),
          '#parents' => array(
            'fields',
            $name,
            'parent',
          ),
        ),
        'hidden_name' => array(
          '#type' => 'hidden',
          '#default_value' => $name,
          '#attributes' => array(
            'class' => array(
              'field-name',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'label' => array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Label display for @title', array(
          '@title' => $instance['label'],
        )),
        '#title_display' => 'invisible',
        '#options' => $field_label_options,
        '#default_value' => $display['label'],
      ),
    );

    // ...

  }
```

Yes, it is possible to use that form element, using the correct data. Since it has been written for a very specific purpose, it's easier to write code for a custom form element, if the task is not showing a table with the same degree of complexity. If the code is then used for a single form, it's even easier to create a custom table in a form.